# Reading a big chunk from stdin - want to go faster

Tags: optimization, python-2.7, stdin

I've researched this on S.O. and do not see any solutions other than the one I am using - but they are all quite old.

in Python 2.7 I'm trying to optimize some code for a programming test. Have to read 10**18 numbers from stdin that are separated by spaces (no newlines at all).

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.read().strip().split(' ')]
```

for a test run, the whole run takes 1.3 seconds with 1.2 of that for the read so this is the only place left to optimize.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Afaik you can't memory map stdin like you could with a file, so I'm not sure how we could reasonable speed this up, considering that read() already buffers the input (maybe that's not completely optimal though)

Comment: I never found any better solutions so I guess that this is the optimum method.